# How to obtain a shared pointer to a member

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Suppose I have a shared pointer to some data structure:

```
struct Data {
    int a;
    int b;
};
shared_ptr<Data> data = make_shared<Data>();
```

Is it possible to obtain a `shared_ptr<int>` to `data->b` which reuses the ref-count of `data`.

I.e. I want to pass a shared pointer to only a part of a reference-counted structure.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I really missed the aliasing constructor.

Comment: So the answer is: `shared_ptr<int> b = shared_ptr(data, &data->b);`.